# Correcting and maintaining org-mode hyperlinks

Tags: org-mode

This is a two part question having to do with [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).

1. Does org-mode provide any functionality for validating hyperlinks, especially local ones? This could be used to combat link rot after the fact.
2. Even better, does org provide functionality so that if I rename a file in dired, it will update affected files? This could prevent some kinds of link rot before it happens, at least for local files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For part 1, I didn't find anything built-in. The following function will provide a list of broken links in the minibuffer. I've tested it on some simple examples, but far from exhaustively.

```
(defun check-bit-rot ()
  "Searches current buffer for file: links, and reports the broken ones."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (beginning-of-buffer)
    (let (file-links)
      (while (re-search-forward org-link-bracket-re nil t)
        (if (string= "file:" (match-string-no-properties 1))
            (if (not (file-exists-p (match-string-no-properties 3)))
                (setq file-links
                      (cons (match-string-no-properties 0)
                            file-links)))))
      (message
       (concat "Warning: broken links in this file:\n"
               (mapconcat #'identity file-links "\n"))))))
```

Comment: Do you think `org-bracket-link-analytic-regexp` would help pick apart Org links? Seems like it was created for tasks just like this one.

Comment: @Constantine yes, thanks! Didn't know about that one.

Comment: Nice. Two possible add-on ideas: (1) add some marking text to bad links to promote discovery via search and/or highlighting; (2) bookmark the bad links.

Comment: Idea (3) make this into a flycheck checker, and the in-buffer highlighting will be done for you.

Comment: Interesting suggestions. I'll dig into it when time permits over the holiday.

Answer (score 19):

Since Org 9.0 you can run the `org-lint` function which, among other things, checks for broken local links.

Comment: How can you narrow down org-lint output to only display broken links?

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a Python script https://github.com/cashTangoTangoCash/orgFixLinks that attempts to repair broken links to local files, within one or more org files on a local drive in the Ubuntu OS.  It is certainly an amateur command line script, but might be worth playing with.  There is a GitHub wiki that provides a degree of documentation: https://github.com/cashTangoTangoCash/orgFixLinks/wiki.  Please check the warnings in the README.

I'm sorry that this Python script is not a part of Org, but completely separate/stand-alone.  I hope no-one is bothered that I am not answering the question of the OP directly; I just thought someone might like playing with the Python script.

Answer (score 0):

```
  (setq org-id-link-to-org-use-id 'create-if-interactive-and-no-custom-id)
```

- use `org-store-link` to store a link (works on non-org files, too)
- use `org-insert-link` to insert the stored link

If you want more features:

- org-super-links
- org-roam

Update: `org` needs some kind of config to actually find the IDs after renames.

One way to do this is to:

- Install `org-roam`
- Set `org-roam-directory` to the root of all your files
- Run `(org-roam-db-build-cache)`, `(org-roam-db-update)`

Another solution is to set `org-id-extra-files` to all the org files you have.

Comment: It's unclear how this answers the OP's question.  Can you please explain?

Comment: @Dan It uses UUIDs instead of file paths to create links, and UUIDs don't rot.

Comment: It's still unclear how your post answers the OP's question.  I've tried your solution briefly by moving files, and the links do not work.

Comment: @Dan You're right. I myself am new to this. I think we need to do some config for org to find the IDs. I'll edit the answer when I figure out the trick.

Comment: Let me suggest that you delete the answer for now, and then either undelete it or post a new answer when you have figured it out.

Comment: @Dan I added a workaround for now.

Comment: This answer would be clearer if you included a 1-2 sentence explanation of what org-roam does that reduces link rot, and link to the documentation of the package.

Comment: @Tyler I don't really know, unfortunately. I came to this question looking for answers, and posted what I pieced together.

Comment: ok. I use org-roam a bit, if I have time later I may add a bit of explanation myself

Comment: HappyFace: I am an avid user of Org Roam, and I think you are onto something by suggesting it.  However, your answer as it stands is not easy to read.  You could include a screenshot showing how links work inside Org Roam.  E.g., https://i.ibb.co/M84bKNt/Screenshot-from-2021-05-19-20-43-02.png  Otherwise, the answer could be improved with some narrative details. "Do this, here's what you get in an example, Do this, here's why" — etc.