# Find broken links and unused IDs

Tags: org-mode, org-link

I extensively use links to refer to different org files/ headings. All my links are created using IDs.

But it might happen that in the course of work, some links might get broken --- the reference is deleted. It also might happen that an ID was created for the heading but the linking never happened.

`org-lint` can identify broken links. But in my case, it identified some working links also as broken links. Secondly, it works only on the current buffer.

Is it possible to generate a list of all the broken links and list of all the unused IDs across all files in directory (including sub-directories)?

Comment: Tyler wrote-up a broken-links check function:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/5431/2287  I modified it a bit for my own needs, but my recollection is that he gave me a really good head-start with the linked answer.  I have not looked-up unused ID's ...

Comment: @lawlist Thanks. I also discovered `org-lint`. But two problems. `org-lint` identified some working links as broken links with high trust. Secondly, these only check the current buffer. I wanted a solution that traverses a directory tree. I have edited the question for this.

Comment: If you can create a minimal example with working links that `org-lint` identifies as broken (or you can trace the code and explain why it is wrong), please post a bug on the Org mode mailing list.

Comment: @NickD Unfortunately, I am not able to create a minimal working example. Here is the output produced by org-lint:      7 high  Unknown ID "4da2fd15-3343-4d2b-9962-4c85492de415"
     7 high  Unknown ID "ef0f88ce-fcab-4220-afda-bc53f22181b4"
     7 high  Unknown ID "5e9ae306-4720-4a3a-a7ce-727cba55399c"
    20 high  Unknown ID "0708d77f-6c4e-4051-9adb-9bcb687efff3"
    27 high  Unknown ID "f0b505b9-6433-42bf-8a18-6ed67eefeb12"
    54 high  Unknown ID "5e9ae306-4720-4a3a-a7ce-727cba55399c"
I have checked all these links. They work without error.

Comment: @NickD  Also, `org-roam-doctor` on the same file produces no error!